# How to code a calculator that adds, numbers consecutively (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, calculator

This is my code for the calculator, right now I can only add **2 numbers** consecutively before hitting the equals sign, I want to make where I can add **More** **than two Numbers** before hitting the equals button. (Written in Swift)

```
import UIKit

class CalcControl: UIView {
var firstEntry = ""
var isUserInMiddleOfTypingNumbers:Bool?
var didUserPressedOperation:Bool?
var op:String?


@IBOutlet var displayLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func digitPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    if (didUserPressedOperation == nil) {
        //displayLabel.text = ""
        didUserPressedOperation = nil
    }

    if (isUserInMiddleOfTypingNumbers == nil) {
        displayLabel.text = displayLabel.text! + sender.currentTitle!
    } else {
        displayLabel.text = sender.currentTitle
        isUserInMiddleOfTypingNumbers = true
    }
        }

@IBAction func operationPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    op = sender.currentTitle
    firstEntry = displayLabel.text!
    didUserPressedOperation = true
    displayLabel.text = ""


}

@IBAction func clearPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    self.clear()
}

func clear() {
    firstEntry = ""
    isUserInMiddleOfTypingNumbers = nil
    didUserPressedOperation = nil
    displayLabel.text = ""
}


@IBAction func equalPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    var secondEntry:NSString = displayLabel.text!
    println((firstEntry))
    println((secondEntry))

    if(op == "+") {
        displayLabel.text = (((firstEntry as NSString!).doubleValue + (secondEntry as NSString).doubleValue) as NSNumber).stringValue
    } else if(op == "-") {
        displayLabel.text = (((firstEntry as NSString!).doubleValue - (secondEntry as NSString).doubleValue) as NSNumber).stringValue
    } else if(op == "x") {
        displayLabel.text = (((firstEntry as NSString!).doubleValue * (secondEntry as NSString).doubleValue) as NSNumber).stringValue
    } else if(op == "/") {
        displayLabel.text = (((firstEntry as NSString!).doubleValue / (secondEntry as NSString).doubleValue) as NSNumber).stringValue
    }


    firstEntry = ""
    isUserInMiddleOfTypingNumbers = nil
    didUserPressedOperation = nil
}

   }
```

Comment: save the old result in an instance variable and keep adding to it... you basically do it already but always reset your firstEntry to be the label text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would adjust your logic so that:

1. There is an IB Action that all the operator keys (+, -, x, /) are tied to.  In this IB Action any time it is activated, there are two choices: a) prepare for another number to be entered or b) the previous key sequence was a number followed by an operator symbol and the button is the same as an Enter.
2. An IB Action for the delete key.  Obvious role.
3. An IB Action for the Enter key.